# Why does sending POST request to asp.net core fail?

Tags: asp.net, cors, axios

I have a ASP.net core API project that I'm trying to send a POST request to in Firefox, but I always get an error saying:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:44302/api/posts. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

And if I look at the request sent, I can see it was an OPTIONS request that returned `204 No Content`. The POST request is not sent at all, which I can verify by checking that the content didn't change.

[image]

Chrome is a different story. Whene I send the same request I get a different error mssage saying:

`POST https://localhost:44302/api/posts net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE`

This time I can see that 2 request send:

[image]

Which look like this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

Finally, if I try in Postman it works totally fine.

This is the code I'm using to send the request:

```
async createPost () {
  const timestamp = new Date()
  const data = {
    title: 'Some test post',
    body: 'Some test content',
    timePosted: timestamp,
    timePublished: timestamp,
    timeUpdated: timestamp,
    isVisible: true
  }
  const response = await axios.post('https://localhost:44302/api/posts', data)
  // do something with the response
},
```

And this is the controller action setup for that route:

```
[HttpPost("api/posts/")]
public ActionResult Create([FromBody] BlogPost blogPost)
{
    _blogPostService.Create(blogPost);
    return CreatedAtAction("Create", blogPost);
}
```

This is the model that I'm using for BlogPost:

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimePosted { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimePublished { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeUpdated { get; set; }

    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I setup CORS:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options => {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", policy => {
            policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials();
        });
    });
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseCors("AllowAll");
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried using `AllowAnyOrigin` instead of `WithOrigins` just for checking if it works?

Comment: I just tried and got the same result.

Comment: Try taking out the `AllowCredentials()` from policy setup code

Comment: Still no luck. If it helps I tried a few more things and I discovered that I don't have this problem if I send a post request without a body.

Comment: I've even tried letting Visual Studio scaffold the controller, and I've tried using the EnableCors attribute on both the controller and the action. Still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with the dotnet core sdk (was on version 2.2.101). See [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4398). Solution was to update to the newest version and now everything works OK.